# javaURLContextFactory ClassNotFound

Tags: java, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

We are trying to get `InitialContext` using a listener in web.xml of our application and getting below error:

```
SEVERE: Unable to init UserDataCachejavax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory]
  at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
  at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:17)
```

This class is present in catalina.jar.
Java version used is jdk1.6.0_02
Tomcat version is tomcat 7

Please let us know if any one has faced this error or is it related to security manager on server?

Comment: You probably included something in the classpath that conflicts with tomcats.  Make sure you only include the class once.

Comment: Hi Hitham, thanks for the response. I am trying to print the classpath from my listener's init() method, and it gives me only 2 jars:
C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;

Is this normal? catalina.jar which has javaURLContextFactory class is not listed here.

Comment: I believe it should give you all jars in the classpath.